# Android - How to launch a Facebook application from other application

Tags: android, facebook

My application has two buttons, *1-Login* and *2.Signup* with Facebook.

I want when I will press the second button, it should open the login activity of the official Facebook application, and after login it should ask for allow the permisson and come back to my application with user information, so that I can create an account for that particular user, like as [Foursquare's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foursquare) signup with Facebook.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for redirecting to the next page after successful login:

After logging in successfully, it will go for the `onComplete()` method, so inside `onComplete()` you get the user details and "redirects to the activity you need".

```
authenticatedFacebook.authorize(Account.this,PERMISSIONS, new TestLoginListener());

public class TestLoginListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
       JSONObject jObject = null;
       jObject = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me"));
       first_name = jObject.getString("first_name");
       email = jObject.getString("email");
       // Further Details you need from Facebook login.
       startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }


    public void onCancel() {
    }


    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: it ll come as a dialog, but i want ofical facebook window ll come. How can i do that?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");startActivity(intent);          this will open the loginactivity of official facebook app. i want after login only it should open that allowpermisson window, .How can i do that?